# Youtube url tester with hyphens

Tags: javascript, regex, youtube

this is how i normally check for youtube url validity using javascript. It works great but fails for urls with "-" before the video id eg `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pIaQpwYEjY`

Any remedy available as I'm not well versed with regex

```
var matches = $('#as_url').val().match(/^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=\w+)(?:\S+)?$/);
if (matches) {
} else {
    error +="\nInvalid Youtube Url";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `\w+` to `[\w-]+`, since the `\w` character class only matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Regular-Expressions.info has a good explanation of [what character classes are](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), as well as the [lookahead feature](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) of regexes, both of which your regex uses.

Comment: Just made the ammendment and tested it with same url but it alerts invalid youtube url

Comment: +1! @Sir Lojik: This works! Just tested it myself. There is probably a typo in your regular expression.

Comment: this fails for me                            var matches = $('#as_url').val().match(/^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=[\w-]+)(?:\S+)?$/);
                            if (matches) {
                                } else {
                                error +="\nInvalid Youtube Url";
                                }

Comment: is there a typo in my query? how comes its failing here. i am starting to get a brain jam